# Why doesn't flask show console log in the right order?

Tags: python, multithreading, http, flask

I have a basic flask application, where one of the routes calls a new thread and returns like this:

```
@app.route("/beginDelivery", methods=["POST"])
def begin_delivery():
if request.get_json(force=True):
    js = request.json
else:
    return jsonify(status=wrong_json())

pid = js['pid']

Thread(target=asynchronously_deliver, args=[pid]).start()
return jsonify(status=0)
```

Now, in my `asynchronously_deliver` function, there is a loop that calls `send_sms` function. `send_sms` does not have any loop and it ends like this:

```
#....
#....
print("sending sms...")
rb = urllib.request.urlopen("someurl").read()
rsp = str(rb.decode('utf-8'))

if rsp[0] == '0' and rsp[1] == '0' and rsp[2] == '0' and rsp[3] == '0':
    provider_id = rsp[7:]
    print("provider: success")
else:
    provider_id = '0'
    print("provider: error")
return provider_id
```

Now, the issue is, that when I examine the console, sometimes, instead of

```
sending sms...
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2016 10:16:54] "GET /someurl HTTP/1.1" 200 -
provider: success
```

I get

```
sending sms...
provider: success
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2016 10:16:56] "GET /someurl HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Meaning that for some reason, in `send_sms` both `print`s where executed before `urllib.request.urlopen("someurl").read()`.

What could be the reason?

**EDIT:**

I added `sleep(10)` to my `/someurl` route and there was a 10 second delay between `sending sms...` and `provider: success`. Although, consider this:

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2016 11:32:06] "GET /someurl
```

wasn't printed until 10 seconds elapsed, right before `provider:success`, therefore, flask doesn't send the message to console until the request is completed and response is returned. Also, that means (I think) that `rb = urllib.request.urlopen("someurl").read()` is **not** called asynchronously. Am I wrong?

Comment: As you said, it's asynchronous. Thus the event occurs whenever the response is received - so it actually is the correct order, printing first what is happening first.

Comment: no, the `send_sms` method itself executes consecutively, without any async calls.

Comment: And how is `urllib.request.urlopen("someurl").read()` output?

Comment: what do you mean, how is?

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your question. How is done what? How is `urllib.request.urlopen().read()` implemented? What does it return?

Comment: How does it work? Is it printing a response "127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2016 10:16:56] "GET /someurl HTTP/1.1" 200 -" asynchronously? I would expect so, since a response can last several seconds under circumstances.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone please see question edit

Comment: I've absolutely no clue of python, however, that seems logical to me.

Comment: There could also be output buffers obfuscating asynchronous outputs (actually writing to buffer, not directly to screen).

Comment: One more idea: Try redirecting stderr stream to a file. The status message might be streamed to stderr and mixed with stdout.